# Consulta jQuery-Ajax com PHP

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

Fiz um código com jQuery-Ajax. Afim de consultar o banco sem muita complicação ou objeções, Apenas  `SELECT * FROM produto`. O resultado foi certo, a partir do momento em que tentei fazer uma consulta com filtro usando a tag `<select><option>` e mandando por ajax a resposta ir para PHP tentando mudar para  `SELECT * FROM produto WHERE Tipo='$_POST[Tipo]'` ele não me retorna nada no site. Quando eu faço a inspeção para ver ele tem algum erro no NETWORK ele mostra a pesquisa certinha por categoria mas não exibe ela no site.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Tipo").on('change', function () {
        var Tipo = ($(this).val());
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '../php/cardapio.php',
            data: {
                Tipo: Tipo,
            },
            success: function () {

            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

```html
   <div class="col-4 pt-1">
                <!-- Select cardapio -->
                <span style="font-size: 10px; color: deepskyblue;">Categoria:</span>
                <br>
                <select id="Tipo" name="Tipo" class="select">
                    <option value="todos" selected>Todos</option>
                    <option value="acais">Açais</option>
                    <option value="tapiocas">Tapiocas</option>
                    <option value="marmitas">Marmitas</option>
                    <option value="bebidas">Bebidas</option>
                </select>
            </div>

        <!-- Tabela cardapio -->
        <div class="row hover-table-layout">
            <div class="cardapio" id="cardapio">
            </div>
        </div>
```

```php
    <?php  

        $pasta = '../img/img_produto/';
        $imagem = glob("$pasta{*.jpg,png,jpeg}", GLOB_BRACE);
        $Tipo = $_POST['Tipo'];
        $result_produto = "SELECT * FROM produto WHERE Tipo='$Tipo'";
        $resultado_produto = mysqli_query($conn, $result_produto);
        while($row_produto = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_produto)){

     echo"
            <div class='listing-item'>
                <figure class='image'>
                    <img class='cardapio-img' src='".$pasta.$row_produto['Img_produto']."' id='produto' alt='".$row_produto['Nome_produto']."'>
                    <figcaption>
                        <div class='caption'>
                        </div>
                    </figcaption>
                </figure>
                <div class='listing'>
                    <h4 class='cardapio-h4'>".$row_produto['Nome_produto']."</h4>
                    <h4 class='cardapio-h4'>".$row_produto['Descricao_produto']."</h4>
                    <h4 class='cardapio-h4'>" .$row_produto['Preco_produto']. "</h4>
                    <button class='btn button-cardapio'>Adicionar</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        "; 
            };
?>
```

Comment: Você pode fazer um teste para ver se seu arquivo PHP esta funcionando, muda isso `$_POST['Tipo']` para isso `$_GET['Tipo']` e depois tenta acessar a url pelo browser `http://seusite.com/php/cardapio.php?Tipo=Bebidas`, veja sé o resultado é o esperado.

Answer (score 0):

Verifique no PhpMyAdmin se a sua consulta está de fato retornando algum registro.

Verifique também os valores dos dados que estão sendo passados pelo ajax.

**No javascript:**

```
success: function(data) {
  console.log(data); // Acesse o console do navegador para visualizar
}
```

**No php:**

```
echo $_POST['Tipo'];
```

Dessa forma você provavelmente chegará no resultado que deseja obter. É importante ressaltar, também, que no código informado nada está sendo feito com o retorno de dados do PHP. Isso deve ser feito no **success**.

**Exemplo**

```
success: function(data) {
  $('#cardapio').html(data);
}
```